# Let f(x)=x ($[\frac{1}{x}]+[\frac{2}{x}]+....+[\frac{8}{x}]$) for x$\neq$ 0 and f(x)=$9k$ for x=0 then value of K for which the function is continous

Tags: continuity

Let f(x) = x ($  [\frac{1}{x}] + [\frac{2}{x}] + [\frac{3}{x}]....+[\frac{8}{x}] $ ) for x$\neq$ 0  and
f(x) = $9k$ for x = 0

then the value of **k**  for which the function is **continous** at x=0 is ([.] denotes greatest integer function)

MY ATTEMPT :  we have to find $\lim_{x\to 0}$ f(x) . I have taken x= $ \frac{1}{t}$  so when x$\to$ 0,  t$\to$$\infty$

so the expression changes to $$ f(x) = \frac{([t] + [2t] + [3t]....+[8t])}{t} $$

then $\lim_{t\to \infty}$ f(x)  looks like $ \frac{\infty}{\infty} $ form but how to use the L-hospital rule with having greatest integer function  I am struck here

Please Help Me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I must say $[t]\sim t$  when $t\to\infty$.